# Calculate surface area from horizontal area and angle

Tags: algorithm, area, slope

I have a shapefile includes polygon features of tilted solar panels and I  used "Calculate Geometry tool" in ArcGIS to find out the projected area of solar panels (horizontal area).

I am looking for ArcGIS tool or an accurate algorithm to calculate surface area, assuming the tilt angle of solar panels is 40 degree.

I found the following formula:

```
Surface Area = Planimetric Area / cosine(Slope Angle)
```

Comment: in `hertz`is more simple expresed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula

```
Surface Area = Planimetric Area / Cosine (Slope Angle)
```

is correct, provided slope angle is measured from the horizontal to the slope (and be sure to convert degrees to radians if the cosine function requires it).

Comment: Hello Martin, 
Thank you for your answer, i would like to ask what you mean by convert degrees to radians if function requires it ? the assumed slope angle from horizontal to slope plane.

Comment: We humans measure angles in degrees (0 - 360 in a circle). However, most computer languages use "natural" angular measures called *radians* (0 - 2pi in a circle). An end-user tool will, most likely, work in user-friendly degrees.

Comment: Hello Martin, yeah it needs radians.